# Runtime error for ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, imageai

When running the code:

```
code ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
```

It gives an error message:

```
return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
RuntimeError: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 unknown device.
```

I also print the ctx.device_name to check why runtime error is given. It prints only a sentence many times, that is:

```
<bound method Context.device of <tensorflow.python.eager.context.Context object at 
0x000002437E8F8CC8>>
```

Is there any way to remove the error?

Comment: Hi @MANJURUL HAQUE, kindly provide the minimum reproducible code and other necessary  details like machine specification.

Comment: @MANJURUL HAQUE, Is your issue resolved now ? Else, can you share reproducible code and device details, It is very difficult to suggest  what was problem without them.